# Combining multiple powershell commands

Tags: powershell, windows-10

I am trying to remove some of the superfluous applications that come with Windows 10 and currently using the below command, for example, if I want to remover 3D Builder, I use:

```
Get-AppxPackage *3dbuilder* | Remove-AppxPackage
```

Similarly, if I need to remove other applications, I need to keep reusing the above command replacing the app name. Is there a way to remove multiple applications with a single command? I do not want to write a powershell script as I need to set the execution policy.

The other option is to use [this](https://www.maketecheasier.com/uninstall-pre-installed-apps-windows-10/) as shown below, but, I would want to see what I remove.

```
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers | Remove-AppxPackage
```

Answer (score 1):

Given what you have described, I'd use a regex match against the package name:

First, run this to verify what you are about to remove:

```
Get-AppXPackage | Where-Object { $_.Name -imatch "(3dbuilder|package2|package3)$" }  | Remove-AppxPackage -WhatIf
```

Then, remove the -WhatIf to actually have Remove-AppXPackage run.

The regex I show above does essentially an ends-with match.  It looks for the packages with names that end with "3dbuilder", "package2", or "package3".  You can add or remove package names from the list, using the Pipe symbol to separate them.  This is because it appears there are some random-ish characters in front of the package names that you probably don't want to type in.

Regexes can match greedily, so be sure to run with -WhatIf first to verify you are only removing what you want!

Comment: `-imatch` is redundant here but it illustrates what is happening. If you don't care whats infront then you can omit the `^.*` part of the string. Also there is no need to escape a trailing dollar sign. It will work without it.

Comment: I edited my code above.  Good suggestions.  I'm a creature of habit, so I always escape dollar signs.